# [Databricks][DatabricksJDBCDriver](500593) Communication link failure. Failed to connect to server. Reason: HTTP Response code: 403

Tags: java, jdbc, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to connect to databricks using java code. Can someone help me please? Here is the code so far I have got::

package digital.eComm.ui.tests;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

```
public class DatabricksSetup {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        String url = "jdbc:databricks://XXXX.azuredatabricks.net:443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1;httpPath=sql/protocolv1/o/XXXXX;AuthMech=3;UID=token;PWD=XXXXXX";
        String username = "token";
        String password = "XXXX"; //Token generated from databricks profile page.

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);


        System.out.println("Database connected!");
        if(connection != null){
            System.out.println("Connection Established");

        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed");
        }

    }

}
```

Below dependancy is already added :

```
  "com.databricks:databricks-jdbc:2.6.25"
```

Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Databricks][DatabricksJDBCDriver](500593) Communication link failure. Failed to connect to server. Reason: HTTP Response code: 403, Error message: Unknown.
    at com.databricks.client.hivecommon.api.HS2Client.handleTTransportException(Unknown Source)
    at com.databricks.client.spark.jdbc.DowloadableFetchClient.handleTTransportException(Unknown Source)
    at com.databricks.client.hivecommon.api.HS2Client.openSession(Unknown Source)
    at com.databricks.client.hivecommon.api.HS2Client.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.databricks.client.spark.jdbc.DowloadableFetchClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.databricks.client.spark.jdbc.DownloadableFetchClientFactory.createClient(Unknown Source)
    at com.databricks.client.hivecommon.core.HiveJDBCCommonConnection.connectToServer(Unknown Source)
    at com.databricks.client.spark.core.SparkJDBCConnection.connectToServer(Unknown Source)
    at com.databricks.client.hivecommon.core.HiveJDBCCommonConnection.establishConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.databricks.client.spark.core.SparkJDBCConnection.establishConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc.core.LoginTimeoutConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at digital.eComm.ui.tests.DatabricksSetup.main(DatabricksSetup.java:16)
Caused by: com.databricks.client.support.exceptions.ErrorException: [Databricks][DatabricksJDBCDriver](500593) Communication link failure. Failed to connect to server. Reason: HTTP Response code: 403, Error message: Unknown.
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`403` is a clear refusal. Server telling you: I know who you are, but you can't do what you're trying to do.

Most likely because the driver is trying to use user/password mechanism to authenticate instead of token in URL because you're explicitly passing the params to `getConnection()`.

replace `DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);` with `DriverManager.getConnection(url);` and try.

Full [example from databricks](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/06/29/connect-from-anywhere-to-databricks-sql.html):

> **Databricks JDBC Driver on Maven**
>
> Java and JVM developers use JDBC as a standard API for accessing databases. Databricks JDBC Driver is now available on the Maven Central repository, letting you use this driver in your build system and CI/CD runs. To include it in your Java project, add the following entry to your application’s `pom.xml`:
>
> ```xml
>     <dependency>
>       <groupid>com.databricks
>       <artifactid>databricks-jdbc</artifactid>
>       <version>2.6.25-1</version>
>     </groupid></dependency>
> ```
>
> Here is some sample code to query data using JDBC driver:
>
> ```java
> import java.sql.*;
>
> public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
>     // Open a connection
>
>     // replace the values below
>     String token = "dapi*****";
>     String url = "jdbc:databricks://********.cloud.databricks.com:443/default;" +      
>                  "transportMode=http;ssl=1;AuthMech=3;httpPath=sql/protocolv1/o/*****;" +
>                  "UID=token;" +
>                  "PWD=" + token;
>
>     try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
>          Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
>          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM samples.nyctaxi.trips");) {
>         // Extract data from result set
>         while (rs.next()) {
>             // Retrieve by column name
>             System.out.print("ID: " + rs.getString("col_name"));
>         }
>     } 
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but still I am facing same error after trying above code

Comment: In that case the token is wrong

Comment: Nope PAT is also valid , I have generated token again

Comment: Hmm, that's curious. I still maintain that `403 is a clear refusal`. So next guesses are 1) user doesn't have permissions to use PAT 2) workspace is configured to disallow tokens 3) user for which you generated the PAT doesn't have permissions to start teh cluster/warehouse or execute query or execute query on that particular schema (though that last one should be a different error) 4) that you're connecting to wrong workspace or cluster. See https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/access-control/tokens.html#control-who-can-use-or-create-tokens and other sections.

Comment: @SeleniumUser did you figure out what the real problem was?

Comment: it was access issue